# How to fix Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to get values firebase and put it into TextView and when I execute my program the exception:

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
> ```

I know that this question is duplicated but I don't found any answer on others.

My code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notificationdisplay);
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    final TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
    final TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    //--------------------String text1="";
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("notification").child("contenu").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.v("text:",dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            text.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    //-----------------title
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("notification").child("title").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.v("title:",dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            title.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
}
```

Comment: psot your activity_notificationdisplay.xml file plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text` is null, so you can't call `setText` on it.  This probably means your inflated view does not have a view inside it with the id "text":

```
final TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);  // text is null
```